# Laravel store data in default timestamp format

Tags: laravel-8

I need to validate and store the date in the default Laravel format.

Form Request class:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'     => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'start_at' => ['required', 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s', 'after:' . now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ],
    ];
}
```

In my controller, there is nothing special I just save this data like below.

```php
$seller->events()->create($request->validated());
```

However, in the response, I receive the data below.

```
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Event 1",
"start_at": "2020-10-18 22:33:58",
"created_at": "2020-09-30T22:42:57.000000Z",
}
```

How can i get **start_at** field in same format as **created_at** ?

Comment: do you always want it in that format when the model is serialized?

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
protected $dates = [
    'start_at',
];
```

On your model